# PHP array not printing

Tags: php, arrays, variables

My print array is not working. it echos out the $articleID just before adds to the array so the variable is not null or anything.

Then i print_r($magIDArray) and it just echo's out 'Array( )'; Can anyone help?

**EDIT:** I have called the function otherwise it wouldn't echo the variables in the function - It wouldent echo $articleID, but it has done

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM master_k2_categories WHERE parent = '$catid' ORDER 
BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    getMagArticleID($id); 
}

$magIDArray = array();
function getMagArticleID($id){
    $magID = $id;
    $sqlID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM master_k2_items WHERE catid = '$magID' ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlID)){
        $articleID = $row["id"];
        echo '<br>', $articleID;
        $magIDArray[] = $articleID;
    }
}
print_r($magIDArray);
```

Comment: Put `$magIDArray = array();` before the `$sql = ...` line and then follow [undone's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19156964/1400370)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed two things:

1) Forgot to call the function.

2) Forgot to return the function value.

Updated code:

```
<?php    
function getMagArticleID($id){
 $magIDArray = array();
    $magID = $id;
    $sqlID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM master_k2_items WHERE catid = '$magID' ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlID)){
        $articleID = $row["id"];
        echo '<br>', $articleID;
        $magIDArray[] = $articleID;
    }
        return $magIDArray;
}

$magIDArray = getMagArticleID($id);
print_r($magIDArray);
```

Comment: Thank you, i not got minus two points because people did not read the bit where i said that i called the function

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `global` keyword:

```
   $magIDArray = array();
    function getMagArticleID($id){
    global $magIDArray ;
    $magID = $id;
        $sqlID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM master_k2_items WHERE catid = '$magID' ORDER BY id DESC");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlID)){
            $articleID = $row["id"];
            echo '<br>', $articleID;
            $magIDArray[] = $articleID;
        }
    }
    getMagArticleID($id);
    print_r($magIDArray);
```

take a look at variable scope:http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You need to run the function first!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your function before you try and echo values

Edit: as [undone said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19156964/1400370) - you'll also have to use a global variable or return a value in the function

Comment: I have called the function first, otherwise it wouldn't echo out all numbers

Comment: Which numbers? include the line where you call the function in your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function first so I would do as follows:

```
$magIDArray = array();
function getMagArticleID($id){
    $magID = $id;
    $sqlID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM master_k2_items WHERE catid = '$magID' ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlID)){
        $articleID = $row["id"];
        echo '<br>', $articleID;
        $magIDArray[] = $articleID;
    }

    return $magIDArray;

}
$magIDfunction = getMagArticleID($id);
print_r($magIDfunction);
```

(UNTESTED)

Comment: You must use keyword or return something!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$magIDArray = array();
function getMagArticleID($id){
    global $magIDArray;
    $magID = $id;
    $sqlID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM master_k2_items WHERE catid = '$magID' ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlID)){
        $articleID = $row["id"];
        echo '<br>', $articleID;
        $magIDArray[] = $articleID;
    }
    return $magIDArray;
}
getMagArticleID(*parameter*);
print_r($magIDArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

your array gets 'filled' inside the scope of the function, therefore its value isn't available in the global scope.

You can either globalize the var:

```
function getMagArticleID($id){
    global  $magIDArray;
    $magID = $id;
    $sqlID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM master_k2_items WHERE catid = '$magID' ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlID)){
        $articleID = $row["id"];
        echo '<br>', $articleID;
        $magIDArray[] = $articleID;
    }
}
```

or you can return the array as a result of the function

```
function getMagArticleID($id){
    $magIDArray=Array();
    $magID = $id;
    $sqlID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM master_k2_items WHERE catid = '$magID' ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlID)){
        $articleID = $row["id"];
        echo '<br>', $articleID;
        $magIDArray[] = $articleID;
    }
    return $magIDArray;
}
$magIDArray=getMagArticleID($id);
```

that is, among other alternatives like passing the array by reference or wrapping it all inside a class in which $madIDArray is a private class var, or declaring $madIDArray as an object and have PDO to fetch the result bound to the object. But I believe you're off to use the simplest solution.